# How to make a SCNNode that is constantly moving at a constant speed?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, swift-playground, scnnode

I'm making a project using Swift playgrounds and I have an SCNPyramid that I want to be constantly moving at a constant speed. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please show what you have done/what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your `node` at constant speed by using `SCNAction`, please have a look into below code for moving your node in `X-axis`, `Y-axis` and `Z-axis`.

```
// Move your node in X-axis
func moveInXaxis() {
    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 2, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 1)
    pyramidNode?.runAction(moveAction, completionHandler: {
        if ShouldContinuteToMoveInXaxis { // Configure your `Bool` to check whether to continue to move your node or not.
            self.moveInXaxis()
        }
    })
}

// Move your node in Y-axis  
func moveInYaxis() {
    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)
    pyramidNode?.runAction(moveAction, completionHandler: {
        if ShouldContinuteToMoveInYaxis { // Configure your `Bool` to check whether to continue to move your node or not.
            self.moveInYaxis()
        }
    })
}

// Move your node in Z-axis
func moveInZaxis() {
    let moveAction = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: 2, duration: 1)
    pyramidNode?.runAction(moveAction, completionHandler: {
        if ShouldContinuteToMoveInZaxis { // Configure your `Bool` to check whether to continue to move your node or not.
            self.moveInZaxis()
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks.